# Converter segundos para timestamp?

Tags: php, data

Estou criando um script PHP para gerar um `json` a partir de um arquivo de legenda `webvtt`, pego o inicio e o fim que estão no formato `minuto:segundo.milisegundo` ou se o vídeo for muito grande eles vem como `hora:minuto:segundo.milisegundo` para futuras comparações no JS no futuro em que o vídeo estiver sendo reproduzido preciso comparar esses valores com o `currentTime` do vídeo que por sua vez entrega o tempo em segundos `segundos.milisegundos` e para facilitar tal comparação eu gostaria que meu PHP já entregasse o tempo de inicio e fim de cada legenda já no mesmo formato que o `currentTime` do vídeo, como posso fazer?

Eis um exemplo:

```
$start = "00:05.570";
$fim = "00:09.700";
```

No exemplo acima seria fácil distinguir que o `currentTime` seria `5.570` e `9.700` como faço para o PHP converter para esse formato?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não entendi, tem um exemplo na pergunta de dois valores e como os mesmo deverão ser entregues pelo PHP

Comment: Não estou seguro de que timestamp compreende milisegundos para conversão do valor....

Comment: Não sei se timestamp seria o termo correto, procurei em alguns lugares mas sempre acho a contrário do que preciso

Comment: Eu quero converter um periodo de tempo que está formato em hh:ii:ss.u para ss.u apenas, ou seja converter o tempo em segundos

Comment: Correto Leo 00:05.570 é 5 segundos e 570 ms

Comment: No seu exemplo os dois primeiros 00 que representam a hora, é um valor dinâmico que pode ou não ser passado para a variável, se o tempo a ser convertido for menor que 1 hora, ele não vai chegar ela no formato completo

Comment: Você quer converter o tempo tudo em segundos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solução

Uma solução utilizando expressões regulares seria, fazendo apenas o valor de segundos obrigatório:

```
function convert($value)
{
    if (preg_match("/(((?P<hours>\d+)\:)?(?P<minutes>\d{1,2})\:)?(?P<seconds>\d{1,2})(\.(?P<milis>\d+))?/", $value, $matches))
    {
        $hours   = intval($matches["hours"]);
        $minutes = intval($matches["minutes"]);
        $seconds = intval($matches["seconds"]);
        $milis   = isset($matches["milis"]) ? intval($matches["milis"]) : 0;

        return sprintf("%d.%d", $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds, $milis);
    }

    return false;
}

// Entrada: horas:minutos:segundos.milis
echo convert("123:12:42.9"), PHP_EOL;   // 443562.9

// Entrada: horas:minutos:segundos.milis
echo convert("01:20:03.7345"), PHP_EOL; // 4803.7345

// Entrada: horas:minutos:segundos.milis
echo convert("0:01:56.23"), PHP_EOL;    // 116.23

// Entrada: minutos:segundos.milis
echo convert("00:05.570"), PHP_EOL;     // 5.570

// Entrada: minutos:segundos.milis
echo convert("00:09.700"), PHP_EOL;     // 9.700

// Entrada: minutos:segundos
echo convert("00:05"), PHP_EOL;         // 5.0

// Entrada: segundos.milis
echo convert("4.55"), PHP_EOL;          // 4.55

// Entrada: segundos
echo convert("12"), PHP_EOL;            // 12.0
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6H8922).

---

### Explicação

A solução foi inteiramente baseada na função nativa do PHP [`preg_match`](http://int%20preg_match%20(%20string%20$pattern%20,%20string%20$subject%20[,%20array%20&$matches%20[,%20int%20$flags%20=%200%20[,%20int%20$offset%20=%200%20]]]%20)):

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

O primeiro parâmetro, `$pattern`, é a expressão regular que iremos analisar. O segundo, `$subject`, é a *string* sobre a qual iremos aplicar a expressão regular e o terceiro parâmetro, `$matches`, será um *array* com os valores da *string* que casaram com o padrão definido na expressão regular.

A expressão regular utilizada divide-se em quatro partes:

```
/(((?P<hours>\d+)\:)?(?P<minutes>\d{1,2})\:)?(?P<seconds>\d{1,2})(\.(?P<milis>\d+))?/
  +-----------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------+
      (horas)               (minutos)             (segundos)          (milis)
```

**Expressão regular: horas**

A expressão regular para as horas, `((?P<hours>\d+)\:)?`, pode ser reduzida para `(\d+\:)?`, que significa *um ou mais dígitos* (`\d+`) *seguido de um caractere :* (`\:`) *opcional* (`?`). A parte `?P<hours>` serve apenas para nomear o grupo; ou seja, se houver um valor que casar com este padrão, crie em `$matches` o índice `hour` com o valor casado. Por exemplo, se a entrada for `01:20:03.7345`, existirá `$matches["hours"]` igual a `01`. Se a hora não for definida, `$matches["hours"]` será `false` (pois definimos que era opcional na expressão regular).

**Expressão regular: minutos**

Vide **horas** (exatamente a mesma lógica, apenas alterando o nome do grupo para `minutes`, `((?P<minutes>\d{1,2})\:)?`). Também alterou-se o quantificador de `+` para `{1,2}`, isso porquê os minutos terão 1 ou 2 dígitos: 1 se for menor que 10 minutos (considerando que pode não ser adicionado o 0 a esquerda) ou 2 dígitos quando de 10 a 59 minutos.

**Expressão regular: segundos**

É basicamente a mesma expressão usada para os minutos, diferenciando apenas que ela será obrigatória, portanto não haverá o caractere `?` no final, `(?P<seconds>\d{1,2})`.

**Expressão regular: milis**

Para os milisegundos, `(\.(?P<milis>\d+))?`, fica: *se definido* (`?`), *deve iniciar com o caractere .* (`\.`) *seguido de um ou mais dígitos* (`\d+`), capturando esse grupo com o nome de `milis`. Repare que o `\.` não faz parte do grupo nomeado, pois queremos apenas o valor numérico, caso contrário, `$matches["milis"]` seria algo como `.570` ao invés de `570`.

Comment: Opa gostei da solução com expressão, vou dar uma estudada na resposta, estou tentando aprender a usar expressões então respostas assim são muito boas, se não for pedir muito você poderia quebrar e explicar as partes da expressão usada no if?

Comment: @LeoLetto veja se ficou claro o suficiente.

Comment: opa, vou testar lá

Comment: Testado, o que já estava bom, ficou melhor ainda. Testado dinamicamente  em  http://kithomepage.com/sos/segundost.php

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss estou fazendo tester aqui, porém da erro caso a entrada seja minutos:segundos.milisegundos, se o tempo em segundos for 00 ele não da erro, mas quando aumenta a função gera um valor que não corresponde ao tempo passado: https://ideone.com/VeP7eR

Comment: @LeoLetto realmente. Se isso aconteceu porque sendo o valor de minutos opcional também, quando informado, ele casa com o valor de horas, então se você entrar com o valor "01:05", ao invés de sair "60*1 + 1", sai "3600*1 + 5".  Para arrumar, basta mover um parenteses, fazendo com que se informado a hora, obrigatoriamente deve ser informado os minutos (o que faz sentido), assim, quando informado apenas os minutos, fica correto. Já fiz a alteração na resposta.

Comment: Nas [revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/202475/revisions) da resposta fica bem claro qual foi o parenteses que alterei, caso tenha dificuldade em localizá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoalmente eu iria preferir trabalhar com a função `DateTime` nativo do PHP

Você teria que setar a data como sendo 01/01/1970, o resto ele faria a conversão...

```
echo timestamp('00:00:30.570')."<br/>"; //30.57
echo timestamp('00:10:30.570')."<br/>"; // 630.57
echo timestamp('12:10:30.570')."<br/>"; // 43830.57

function timestamp($horario){
    list($sec, $msec) = explode('.', $horario);
    $date = '01/01/1970 '.$sec;
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $date, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
    $timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
    return $timestamp+($msec/1000);
}
```

Ai ficaria a cargo de você definir melhor como gostaria do retorno, depende muito da sua necessidade e de como pretende trabalhar daqui /\ pra frente

Comment: Como seria um exemplo, levando em consideração que a string para converter pode ser apenas min:seg.ms sem a hora no começo?

Comment: Nesse caso eu teria que fazer um regex para verificar se a string recebida está ou não no formato hh:ii:ss.uu, correto?

Comment: Com entrada 00:09.700 sem a hora dando erro PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in